# Two line title in footline of warsaw theme

Tags: beamer, presentations, themes

The title of my work is quite large but it shows only half of it in toolbar when i use warsaw theme! is there any way to correct this like make it double line or something ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{This title is large and does not fit into the bar down for each page how can i fit it there ? }
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply use a short title, nobody will read it anyway in the toolbar.

Comment: @Johannes_B this is not a solution, however, how can I make it short in toolbar but keep the title as it is in the slide ?

Comment: Pretty simple: `\tile[short title for the footer]{long title for the title frame with many information}`

Comment: @samcarter I liked and accepted your answer

Comment: @Learner Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I find the [suggestion of @Johannes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236607/have-problem-with-warsaw-theme/358631#comment561159_236607) to use a short title better, but if you insist on two lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{This title is large and does not fit into the bar down for each page how can i fit it there ? }
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4.5ex,dp=2.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4.5ex,dp=2.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
    \parbox{.45\paperwidth}{\inserttitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame. This is a text in first frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]